# Trying to make a custom song player in REACT.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to setup a custom song player with back, forward, play and pause buttons.
I have made the html buttons and added CSS to it. I'm struggling with the JS. I made this same design in regular js (without react) and it worked.

Here is the code in question

```
import React from 'react'
import back from "./rss/icons/back.png";
import next from "./rss/icons/next.png";
import pause from "./rss/icons/pause.png";
import play from "./rss/icons/play.png";
import song1 from "./rss/music/AgarTumSathHo.mp3";
import song2 from "./rss/music/AllOfMe.mp3";
import song3 from "./rss/music/CheapThrills.mp3";

export default function MusicPlayer() {
    const player = document.getElementById("player");
    const songList = [song1, song2, song3];
    let [songs, setSongs] = React.useState([song1]);
    let [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = React.useState(false);
    let [nowPlaying, setNowPlaying] = React.useState(songs[0]);
    

    function TogglePlay() {
        if (!isPlaying) {
            setIsPlaying(true);
            player.play();
            document.getElementById('playIcon').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('pauseIcon').style.display = "inline";
        } else {
            setIsPlaying(false);
            player.pause();
            document.getElementById('playIcon').style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById('pauseIcon').style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function nextSong() {
        setIsPlaying(true);
        setNowPlaying(songs[nowPlaying + 1]);
        player.play();
    }

    return (
        <div id="media">
            <audio controls id="player">
                <source src={nowPlaying} type="audio/mp3" />
            </audio>
            <div class="inline">
                <div id="backLink" class="inline">
                    <button>
                        <li class="nav-button music-button" id="back">
                            <img id="backIcon" src={back} alt="back"/>
                        </li>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="midLink" class="inline">
                    <button onClick={TogglePlay}>
                        <li class="nav-button music-button" id="playPause">
                            <img id="playIcon" src={play} alt="play" />
                            <img id="pauseIcon" src={pause} alt="pause" />
                        </li>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="nextLink" class="inline">
                    <button onClick={nextSong}>
                        <li class="nav-button music-button" id="next">
                            <img id="nextIcon" src={next} alt="next"/>
                        </li>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slidecontainer">
                <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="volSlider" />
            </div>

            <div id="nowPlaying">
                <p id="songName">Press Play</p>
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}
```

I am trying to set the songs to an array of songs which can be used to select nowPlaying which then gets injected into the source for the player(audio). It's not letting me setSongs() or anything. Please help!